# ANTLRv4: How to read double quote escaped double quotes in string?

Tags: antlr4

In ANTLR v4, how do we parse this kind of string with double quote escaped double quotes like in VBA?

for text:

```
"some string with ""john doe"" in it"
```

the goal would be to identify the string: *`some string with "john doe" in it`*

And is it possible to rewrite it to turn double double quotes in single double quotes? `"" -> "`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like this:

```
STRING
 : '"' (~[\r\n"] | '""')* '"'
 ;
```

where `~[\r\n"] | '""'` means:

```
~[\r\n"]    # any char other than '\r', '\n' and double quotes
|           # OR
'""'        # two successive double quotes
```

> *And is it possible to rewrite it to turn double double quotes in single double quotes?*

Not without embedding custom code. In Java that could look like:

```
STRING
 : '"' (~[\r\n"] | '""')* '"' 
   {
     String s = getText();
     s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1); // strip the leading and trailing quotes
     s = s.replace("\"\"", "\""); // replace all double quotes with single quotes
     setText(s);
   }
 ;
```

Comment: works like a charm. side question, is it possible to rewrite it to turn double double quotes in single double quotes?  "" -> "?  thanks!

Comment: @JayDee see my revised answer.

Comment: For me using ANTLR 4 the following rule worked with both double quoted and single quoted strings:
STRING : '"' (~[\r\n"] | '""')* '"' | '\'' (~[\r\n\'] | '\'\'')* '\'';

Comment: @Sasha your string throws "invalid escape sequence \'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: set is empty"

Comment: @AlexeySh. I assume that's because I copy-pasted from a C# program and you pasted it into java program where escaping a double-quote is done differently (not through '\')

Comment: Different ANTLR versions might react differently for `~[\r\n\']`. ANTLR 4.8 produces an error. It should be `~[\r\n']`