# Custom C# Code in ANTLR4

Tags: c#, antlr4

I am trying to add some custom code in my ANTLR4 grammar to do some processing on the tokens before they are handed off. What I am trying to do is strip leading/trailing quotes from the token. I tried converting the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17897968/3101082), but get the following error:

> Lexer.cs(110,24): error CS0103: The name `getText' does not exist in the current context
>
> Lexer.cs(112,16): error CS0103: The name `setText' does not exist in the current context

I then read on another StackOverflow post that someone had to use `$text` instead of `setText()`, but that leads to this error:

> error(128): Grammar.g4:105:22: attribute references not allowed in lexer actions: $text

Is there a way to put custom code in an ANTLR4 grammar? Here is the relevant grammar rule:

```
STRING_LITERAL : '"' (~["\r\n\\])* '"'
                 {
                   var s = $text;
                   s = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2);
                   $text = s;
                 };
```

Or likewise with `getText()` and `setText()` in the place of `$text`.

**EDIT**

I am using ANTLR 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

I was close. I figured out in C# they use a `Text` property instead of `getText()` and `setText()` method. So the above grammar rule becomes:

```
STRING_LITERAL : '"' (~["\r\n\\])* '"'
                 {
                   var s = Text;
                   s = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2);
                   Text = s;
                 };
```