# ANTLRv4 : Read double quotes escaped with both \ and "

Tags: string, antlr4

I'm trying to implement a parser using ANTLRv4 for a language that accepts both "" and \" as a way escaping " characters in " delimited strings.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897651/antlrv4-how-to-read-double-quote-escaped-double-quotes-in-string) show how to do it for "" escaping. However when I try to extend it to also cover the \" case, it almost works but becomes too greedy when two strings are on the same line.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar strings;
strings : STRING (',' STRING )* ;

STRING
 : '"' (~[\r\n"] | '""' | '\"' )* '"' 
 ;
```

Here is my input of three strings:

```
"This is ""my string\"",
"cat","fish"
```

This correctly recognises "This is ""my string\"", but thinks that "cat","fish" is all one string.
If I move "fish" down on to the next line it works correctly.

Can anyone figure out how to make it work if "cat" and "fish" are on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `STRING` rule non greedy to stop at the first quote char it encounters, instead of trying to get as much as possible:

```
STRING
 : '"' (~[\r\n"] | '""' | '\"' )*? '"' 
 ;
```

Comment: This makes the "cat", "fish" part work correctly, but completely breaks the escaping part.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I need to do to get this to work as I wanted, though to be honest I'm still not entirely sure why Antlr was doing what it did.

Simply by adding another backslash character to the `'\"'` clause it works!

So my final STRINGS definition is : `'"' (~[\r\n"] | '""' | '\\"' )* '"'`

Going back to first principles, I hand drew a state transition diagram of the problem and then realised that the two escaping mechanism sequences are not the same and cannot be treated similarly. Then trying to implement the two patterns in AntlrWorks it became apparent that I needed to add the second backslash at which point it all started working.

Does a single backslash followed by some arbitrary character simply mean that character?